# Swift 3 iOS 10 - Apply the "Slide to Unlock" animation to a label

Tags: ios, animation, swift3

I want to use the "slide to unlock" animation from iOS for a button. I just want the animation not the function behind it.
To be honest I have no idea how to start. I googled this a while, but I found nothing for Swift 3.

[Here is what I want in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyWhx.png)

Comment: Use an open source control from [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=unlock), or dig their source code and make your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Shimmer from Facebook. They use it for loading but its usable on labels. Looks very similar to the iOS “Slide to Unlock”.

[Shimmer](https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer)

[image: Shimmer Example]